# Why would the solution and the project be in totally different locations?

Tags: visual-studio, backup, projects-and-solutions, special-folders

I just noticed that my one-project solution is in:

C:\Users\Clay\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Platypus\Platypus.sln

...whereas the project itself is in:

C:\Platypus

What is the sense of separating things out that way? I did choose the project's folder, but not the solution's. I can see why the "buried" location would be used if I hadn't chosen a specific separate location for my project, but I would expect that choice to have put the project AND the solution in that folder.

Seems like a weird way to run a ship.

Is this normal? Any "gotchas" as far as backing it up goes? IOW, is backing up the project enough, or do I need to explicitly back up both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default location at which the solution file is created however if you want to change the location of the solution file then try when you create the project simply uncheck the default box for "create directory for solution". This will create the File (.sln) in the same directory as the web project. Or you may start with a Blank Solution under "Other Project Types-->Visual Studio Solutions" in the New Project dialog after that add your website.